# Cancel Async/Await

Tags: javascript, async-await, angular6, es6-promise

I have a function like below

```
function async populateInventories(custID){
    this.inventories = await this.inventoryService.getCustomerInventories(custID)

    //do some stuff with Inventories

    // another await 

}
```

My Problem is I need to cancel a Ongoing Await request, and send a Fresh Await request like we do Using Subscription.

Previously my Function was like below where in i was able to cancel Previous subscription:

```
function async populateInventories(custID){

    let invetroySubscription$;

    if(invetroySubscription$!==undefined){
        invetroySubscription$.unsubscribe();
    }

    invetroySubscription$=this.inventoryService.getCustomerInventories(custID).subscribe((data:any)=>{
        this.inventories = data.response;

        //do some stuff with Inventories


         // another subscription here -- I was told this way of doing is wrong

    })

}
```

With async/await i was able to handle any operation sequentially which is really great and code was very much readable with which i was not able to achieve using subscriptions but async/await came with their own drawbacks.

*I can stop Multiple Calls at a time to **populateInventories** to Avoid my problem,  But i am looking if i can get any more solutions(neat) to my problem.*

**PS:I read calling another subscription in a subscribe call or nested subscriptions is not a good Practice.**

Comment: It looks like `.getCustomerInventories(custID)` doesn't return a promise. It (synchronously) returns a stream-like object that can be subscribed to. So your original code won't be improved by awaiting `getCustomerInventories`. In fact, awaiting it and treating the result as your data (rather than a stream that gets your data) is almost certainly a mistake.

Comment: From what you are trying to achieve, your async logic is wrong. You do not go for a fresh await of a promise, you change the promise logic to cater for additional/fresh requests, i.e. you update `inventoryService.getCustomerInventories` implementation so it can refresh the request internally, chained to the promise it returns.

Answer (score 5):

Handling the cancellation of an asynchronous actions depends on the **type** and the **way** we are executing the async action.

I assume that the **type** of our asynchronous actions are HTTP requests. Therefor we have several options how we execute a actual HTTP request:

1. using **HttpClient** from Angular itself (*most common case and the best practice!*)
2. using **Axios** (afaik a wrapper around the Fetch API)
3. using **Fetch API** provided by the browser itself

---

### HttpClient

When using the `HttpClient` service from Angular itself it is recommended to use it with `RxJs` in combination. So in your case I would switch back to the Observable solution you have described above. Why?:

- HttpClient itself uses `RxJs` and returns Observables as a default
- `RxJs` in combination with the `HttpClient` makes it "easy" to cancel an ongoing request with its **switchMap** operator
- Be aware that **switchMap** itself does not cancel the HTTP request or keeps the logic for it. It just calls [unsubscribe](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/switchMap.ts#L133) on the subscription of the inner stream. The request cancel logic is provided by the implementation of **[HttpClient](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L336)** (more or less) which returns the cancellation logic in the unsubscribe callback.
- Unfortunately it's not that easy to write proper `RxJs` code and avoid multiple or nested subscriptions. In your case I would try to create a stream of (I assume) click events and use:

  - [switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) to flatten the stream (compareable to `flatMap`) and unsubscribe from an existing inner stream in case a new click-event
    occurs.
  - [concatMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) to wait until the completion of the `inventoriesRequest` stream, before the `populateInventoriesRequest` is made.

```js
 this.populateInventoryClicks$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.inventoryService.inventoriesRequest()),
    concatMap(inventories => this.inventoryService.populateInventoriesRequest(inventories)),
  )
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Please take a look at the **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cancel-http-calls?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** example. Throttle your speed in the network tab in the dev console. 
In the network tab we should then see that on multiple button clicks only the last request is completed and that all before got canceled.
[image]

---

### Axios

When using the Axios client, we can use the `cancel` method it provides for us. Take a look at their [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md#cancellation) if your interested in their approach. 
Be aware that when we are using Axios no **HttpInterceptors** from Angular will run on these requests. This is the most obvious reason why I know nobody using it in combination with Angular.

---

### Fetch API

The Fetch API also provides us with the possibility to abort an ongoing request made with `fetch`. I can't recommend this approach for the same reasons I can't recommend the Axios approach. But take a [look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort) at it if you are interested.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I don't see how it relates to the question.  Your point, I think, is that we don't cancel promises, we cancel async actions that return promises.  The OP seems to be dealing with a streams, not promises.

Comment: The `HttpClient` part deals with streams. The point is that in Angular it is way easier to use `HttpClient` in combination with RxJs, especially in cancellation use cases, and therefor no promises.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a callback of sorts inside of the getCustomerInventories function that resolves or rejects the promise when you want it canceled. 
For example, if you wanted it to stop and send a new one based on time, you could add something like

```
setTimeout(resolve, ms);
```

to it.

You could use [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) to retrieve either the original await or your timeout or whatever it is. Something like:

```
//keepGoing and checkGoingFunction could be whatever you need them to be but something that returns a promise that will resolve or reject when you want to "cancel" the await
var keepGoing = true;
var checkGoingFunction = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        while(keepGoing){
          //just filling time and keeping a loop, maybe not efficient but working
        }
        //after it exits (when you change keepGoing to false)
        resolve("timedOut");
    });
}

function async populateInventories(custID){
    //a promise returned by your method
    var custInvPromise = this.inventoryService.getCustomerInventories(custID)
    var timeoutPromise = checkGoingFunction(); //promise from timeout function
    var bigPromise = Promise.race(custInvPromise, timeoutPromise);
    //maybe add setTimeout(function(){keepGoing = false}, 5000); if you wanted to timeout after 5 seconds

    var result = await bigPromise;
    if(result == "timedOut"){
       //resend await or whatever you need to do
    } else {
        this.inventories = result;
        //do some stuff with Inventories
    }




}
```

Comment: It's almost certainly the case that getCustomerInventories(custID) does not return a promise.

Comment: @danh ah, i don't know much about subscriptions, my bad :)